# Only display last record in my datareader in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

In MsgBox show the only last rows of database result..
i want to add sql result to datagrid using rows.add function..

```
    Try
        GetDataConn(".", "restaurant", True)
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT i.item_id as 'item', i.item_name as 'name', i.price as 'price', t.item_qty as 'qty' FROM item_tbl i, temp_tbl t WHERE t.item_id = i.item_id AND t.table_id ='" & id.Trim & "' ", sqlConn)
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        myreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
        myreader.Read()
        While myreader.hasRow()
            'frmMain.posdatagrid.Rows.Add(myreader.Item("item"), myreader.Item("name"), myreader.Item("price"), myreader.Item("qty"), myreader.Item("price") * myreader.Item("qty"))
            MsgBox(myreader.Item("item"))
            myreader.NextResult()
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        sqlcmd.Dispose()

    End Try
```

Comment: Try to convert your `SELECT` to `SELECT TOP(1)`. This will give you ony first row returned from the query execution.

Comment: _Using rows.Add_ is a requirement or you are allowed to use the standard DataSource property of the grid?